# On button click at bottom direct go to input field at top?

Tags: jquery

is it possible to click on the button at the footer and go directly to the top form input field?

Button is

```
<a href="#">Get Free Quote</a>

<ul>
<li class-"col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="text-836" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7- 
validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name*">
</li>
<li class-"col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="text-836" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7- 
validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name*">
</li>
</ul>
```

I want something like When someone clicks on the get free quote button page scroll to the top and it automatically enters in the first field.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you would need to use JavaScript though.

Here is an example:

```
// get the two elements
const buttonElement = document.getElementById(“buttonId”)
const inputElement = document.getElementById(“inputId”)

// add an on click listener to the button
buttonElement.addEventListener(‘click’, function () {
    // when clicked focus on the input element
    inputElement.focus()
})
```

Comment: Not working for me. Will you please check it again ?

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you edit the two const’s at the top? You have to. Also make sure you put this in the script tags.

Comment: Actually, i have a banner with the form at top of the page and have a button at the footer so I only want that when someone clicks on the button at the footer, page scrolls to the top and the user automatically enters in the form first field.

Comment: Yeah, I know. What html and JavaScript did you try tho?

Comment: Html I wrote above and don't know about jquery

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `focus()` -> `$(your selector).focus()`, it automatically scrolls and gives the focus to the desired item